# Exporting Tensorflow prediction to csv but the result contains all zeros - Is this because of one-hot ending ?

Tags: python, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

I am using Tensorflow framework for my classification predictions. My dataset contains around 1160 output classes. The output class values are 6 digit number. For example, 789954. After training and testing the dataset with Tensorflow, I got the accuracy of around 99%.

Now the second step is to get the prediction outcome in the csv file so that I can check the predicted outcomes(logits) match with original labels in the set. We know that logits are one hot encoded vectors for my . So, I have done the following steps in order to decode the one hot encoded.

```
prediction=tf.argmax(logits,1)
print(prediction.eval(feed_dict={features : test_features, keep_prob: 1.0}))
prediction = np.asarray(prediction.eval(feed_dict={features : test_features, keep_prob: 1.0}))

prediction = np.reshape(prediction, (test_features.shape[0],1))
np.savetxt("prediction.csv", prediction, delimiter=",")
```

The resulted values in csv file is only 0.00E+00 for all entries. But my expectation is 6 digit codes for the respective csv entries. I guess I have gone somewhere wrong in my one-hot encoding.

Any help is appreciable.

**Added :** 
I have one hot encoded in this way.

```
labels = tf.one_hot(labels, n_classes)
```

And n_classes = 1160 and all the values will be 6 digit number

Comment: 0.00E+00 in csv file.

Comment: Check with `np.savetxt("prediction.csv", prediction, fmt='%d',delimiter=",")`  .The problem may be all the prediction is pointing to first class.

Comment: Hi I would like to explain the problem statement. 

for the description, "Airtel bill" - the respective code is 457857
"fit bit" - 788978
"google home" - 959546


So For each description, there are respective codes. So I used countvectorizer of sklearn to get the vector for each description and ran a NN model to find the classification for new data. 


Isn't this model fine to perform this data ? 


Like you said, if all the prediction points to first class, Then Why am I getting the accuracy of 100% ?

Comment: Yours is a multi-label problem?. The labels have more than one-bins as one? Is all the predictions in your csv file zero?. If yes, then your accuracy calculation is wrong.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: yes . there are 1160 unique labels are there. For each description, there will be one 6 digit code available. So when my model sees a new data, it has to predict the code for the new description based on the trained data

Comment: yes for what question? You didnt answer to any of the question i posted above. If each description has only one-label then your approach is fine, its not a multi-label problem. You use sklearn LabelEncoder to convert your categories to labels. Your label should be for each feature a value between [0 to 1160] and then do a on-hot encoding.

Comment: Thanks Vijay. mine is not a multilabel problem. I guess I have to use sklearn's LabelEncoder to make it between 0 and 1160 and after that one hot.

Comment: Hi @vijay m. Please check this too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227229/logits-and-labels-mismatch-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each description has only `one-label` then your approach is fine. You use `sklearn LabelEncoder` to convert your categories to labels. Your label should be for each feature a value between `[0 to 1160]` and then do a `on-hot encoding`.